# Query string on API-s

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot

I am trying to build an API mostly to have some hands on experience on building API-s since I never worked with API before. So far I have all the basic methods GET/POST/PUT/DELETE working fine. 
When I call the method GET :

```
http://localhost:8100/apis/employee
```

It returns all the employees on database which this part makes sense. My question is how can implement filter to say only get employees that has let say firstName = john
I know that I can say

```
http://localhost:8100/apis/employee/1
```

and it will pull the employee with id=1 but I don't want that.

To make it clear my question is, How do I treat a request like this on my GET method

```
http://localhost:8100/apis/employee/?firstName=john&lastName=smith
```

This is how my GET function looks like. I am using SpringBootApplication

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getAllEmployees() {


    List<Employee> employeeList = (List<Employee>)employeeRepository.findAll();

    if (employeeList.size() == 0) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
    return Response.ok(employeeList).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't need to be pluralized, there is only one API.

That said, you do want to pluralize your employees collection, because there are multiple employees and you are filtering through them.

You can absolutely filter through the collection as you have suggested. The code is just as trivial as creating a hash of all the options you'd like to filter by (probably whitelist them), then just do that in your code.

This is then just a question about how to turn options into a query, not actually anything to do with REST or APIs.